# If ions are stable, then why does a battery have an expiration date?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, charge, batteries, electrochemistry

I am talking about non-rechargable batteries. As far as I understand, ions in a battery are stable form of atoms, just having excess electrons, or lesser electrons (relative to the neutral atom).

[image]

Now if the ions are stable, then what causes the battery to expire in about 10 years? Does this mean that the charge from the battery will be lost (how, if the ions do not decay), or that the battery will be unsafe (because of the acid)?

Question:

1. If ions are stable, then why does a battery have an expiration date?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question shows a commercial brand.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-discharge

Comment: @my2cts Is that a rule ?  If so you could have addressed it by e.g. editing out the image yourself or asking the OP to.

Comment: @StephenG Why not you yourself?

Comment: Ions are only stable when isolated.

Comment: @my2cts I have edited the picture.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stable" depends on your point of view and timetable; it is not an absolute.

The battery is an engineered product and designed for a price point to allow it to have a particular lifetime.  There are several things that may limit the length of useful storage, but you'd have to know the particular product to know what they consider in setting the dates.

The ions are electrically stable in the short term because they are kept separated.  Any flaws in the case or the electrolyte allow them to react more quickly, reducing the useful charge inside.  All cells will have some amount of self-discharge.  You can reduce it by using more robust materials.  I'm sure the commercial products keeps it to a low level so that the storage time is reasonable, without spending too much on the case and other parts.

The materials in the common alkaline cell are not chemically stable in air.  If any leaks develop, the electrolyte inside will react and form crystals, further damaging the product.

Comment: Thank you so much!